# Prolog dungeon game and how to block something

Tags: prolog

so i am making a dungeon puzzle game, i have rooms connected, i set up monsters and rules for killing them except i failed to realize that i can bypass monster and move on to the next room without fighting him. here are some rules.

```
alive(skeleton).

path(room1,s,room26).
path(room26,n,room1).
path(room26,w,room27).
path(room27,e,room26).
path(room27,s,room28):-alive(skeleton).
path(room28,n,room27).

kill :-
        i_am_at(room27),
        at(sword, in_hand),
        retract(alive(skeleton)),
        write('You hack repeatedly at the skeleton'), nl,
        write('He screams in agony.'), nl,
        write('grats on killing it.'),
        nl.
```

Ok so how can i set up a rule for room(the one right now is wrong, its opposite of what i want) to say that i can move on as long as there is no fact alive(skeleton).

Comment: You need to separate the presence of things in rooms into a separate predicate. Right now you're actually associating the skeleton with the path between two rooms, not even the room itself! You need more kinds of fact.

Comment: It may help to look into the implementation of other similar text-based adventure games. You can find three examples at: https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/tree/master/examples/adventure At the very least you can have fun playing them (a good excuse for procrastinating doing your own puzzle game :-)

Comment: Both comments are good, but to answer you directly: you mean `not(alive(skeleton))`?

How are you dealing with "move" commands? I imagine you have a clause for a predicate `south` or `s`